# Is there a way to have Xcode auto-align variable names like in Apple's example code?

Tags: xcode

Apple's example projects often have the variable names aligned, in addition to their type specification/general code indentation:

```
  NSUInteger        level;
  double            fadeSpeed;
  CGPoint           ballPosition;
  int               keyOffset;
```

As opposed to:

```
  NSUInteger level;
  double fadeSpeed;
  CGPoint ballPosition;
  int keyOffset;
```

Is there a shortcut to make this happen? (I don't know what it would be called or else I could search the docs for it.)

Comment: Why not simply use the appropriate number of TABs?

Comment: @H2CO3 Laziness I guess. Times n lines of code, a little goes a long way. (http://www.howtogeek.com/102420/geeks-versus-non-geeks-when-doing-repetitive-tasks-funny-chart/)

Comment: Yeah maybe. For example in the game Doodle Jump, there's a main game class with some 400 ivars.

Comment: Yep, that's a lot of tabs to potentially save. Uncrustify-ho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popular pretty-printer [`uncrustify`](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) has at least a dozen different variable alignment parameters that you can specify in its config file. Tony Arnold's project shows you how to use `uncrustify` as an [automator service](https://github.com/tonyarnold/Xcode-4-Uncrustify-Automator-Services) (which means that you can access it from Xcode or any other editor). Robert Payne suggests [using it from a shell script](http://robertjpayne.com/post/9092159751/using-uncrustify-directly-in-xcode-4) that you can incorporate into your build process.

My guess is that Apple runs its examples through `uncrustify` or some other pretty-printer before publishing so that they're all formatted using a common style. It may take some fiddling if you want to exactly reproduce Apple's style, but at a minimum it should be pretty easy to get your variable declarations to align the way you want. It's been a while since I played with all the options, but I'd start by looking at the `align_var_def_span`, `align_var_def_thresh`, and `align_var_def_gap` settings.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/). I've not used it in anger myself, but the feature list seems to include your requirement:

> **Features**
>
> - Ident code, aligning on parens, assignments, etc
> - **Align on '=' and variable definitions**
> - Align structure initializers
> - Align #define stuff
> - Align backslash-newline stuff
> - Reformat comments (a little bit)
> - Fix inter-character spacing
> - Add or remove parens on return statements
> - Add or remove braces on single-statement if/do/while/for statements
> - Supports embedded SQL 'EXEC SQL' stuff
> - Highly configurable - 412 configurable options as of version 0.59

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is already a shortcut, but you can create a program which accepts a big string as input (variables) and the output would be the aligned version of this. Writing this program should not cause too many problems.

Answer (score -1):

There is no built in function in Xcode to do that automatically, however you can easily align variable names with <kbd>tab</kbd> . You have to press <kbd>tab</kbd> after the type multiple time and align to the same width .

Comment: Fairly clear that this is an option, right? Hope I don't look that ill-informed...

Comment: Sorry, but i think that there is no other way ... You can look for a plugin.